# Multiple records for same id and i don't want to pull if id is not matching

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table 1 which is like this:

```
Id     Values   
100     1  
100     2  
100     3  
110     1  
110     2  
110     4  
120     3
```

I want the id where there is no 1 and 2 so my result should be like this

```
ID  Values
120  3
```

Comment: What does table 1 have to do with this?  Hint:  `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: sorry this was my first post and i couldn't post it correctly

Comment: Yes i don't need the table 1

Comment: I just want the Id where i dont have the values 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this.

```
SELECT id
    ,values_t
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Table1 t2
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id
            AND t2.values_t IN (
                1
                ,2
                )
        );
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fd80/4)

Comment: Thanks you for response

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Values 
FROM table2
WHERE Id Not in (select Id from table2 where Values IN (1,2))
```

this is your query

Comment: I cant go by Id in the where Condition because there might be some Id where it will start at 2 as well

Comment: Did you get your o/p ?

Comment: tell me your complete requirement. what are  the ID's u want to find?

Comment: I mean i have all the Id's that start from 1 to all the way 110258 and i just want to get the id's where i dont have 1 or 2 values

Comment: Thanks you for response

Comment: I have updated it again I hope you wil get your desired o/p

Answer (score 0):

This makes a select of all data without id=1 or id=2

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE values != 1 OR values != 2
```

Also you can use this as WHERE:

```
WHERE values > 2
```

Comment: But i am still getting the Id 100 and 110 as well. I don't want those Id in my result set

Comment: the ids 100 and 110 are from values 3 and 4, you said you don't want values 1 and 2 but you didn't say nothin about 3 and 4...

Comment: Sorry albert for confusion

100 and 110 has 1 & 2 values so i don' want to have them in my result set, even though they have other values i still don't want them on the result set. I just want those Id's where i don't have the  1&2 values at all.

Comment: Thanks you for response